# Finding angle between two points in an image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to find the angle between two points in an image. The angle is with reference to the centre line of the camera.

[image]

In this image the center point is along the center of the image (assumption, I still have to figure out how to actually calculate it) and I want to find the angle between the line connecting point 1 and the camera center and the line connecting the desired point and the camera center

Now I want to know two things about finding the angle 
 - Is it possible to know the angle if the distance is not known exactly (but can be estimated by a human at run time) Assuming both points lie in the same plane in the image 
 - If the points are not in the same plane, how should I handle the angle calculation?

Comment: do you know the coordinates of the camera center?

Comment: I'm assuming that is the center of the image itself

Comment: You mean that center of camera lies on the image plane?

Comment: Yes, that is my assumption

Comment: Are you looking for cos(angle) = scalar_product(view_direction, vector_from_camera_to_point) ?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. How do I find these two vectors? (view_direction... )

Comment: @user3079474 You should have all information available. If not, you can not solve your problem.

Comment: Am I missing something here - there are three points (2 on the image and where the camera is!)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space).

[image: inner product]

If you are talking in 3D space so your `x`(vector) and `y`(vector) should be in the form `[a,b,f]`(a and b are points) where f is the distance of image plane from the camera center and `a` and `a` are the corresponding coordinates in the camera frame.

If it is in 2D space, so you have to specify the origin of your frame and find `a` and `b` according to that frame and your `x` and `y` vectors are in the form `[a,b]`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be found by using this formula:
[Angle between two rays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ycK.png)

K is the camera matrix. x1 and x2 are the image points given in homogeneous form like [u,v,1] and d1 and d2 are the corresponding 3D points.

See Richard Hartley, Australian National University, Canberra, Andrew Zisserman, University of Oxford: “Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision”, 2nd edition, p. 209 for more details.

Inverting the camera matrix is quite simple. See
https://www.imatest.com/support/docs/pre-5-2/geometric-calibration-deprecated/projective-camera/ for more details.